# R error type "Subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, loops

I am simulating a correlation matrix, where the 60 variables correlate in the following way:

- more highly (0.6) for every two variables (1-2, 3-4... 59-60)
- moderate (0.3) for every group of 12 variables (1-12,13-24...)

  ```
  mc <- matrix(0,60,60)   
  diag(mc) <- 1

  for (c in seq(1,59,2)){    # every pair of variables in order are given 0.6 correlation
  mc[c,c+1] <- 0.6
  mc[c+1,c] <- 0.6
  }


  for (n in seq(1,51,10)){        # every group of 12 are given correlation of 0.3 
    for (w in seq(12,60,12)){     # these are variables 11-12, 21-22 and such.
      mc[n:n+1,c(n+2,w)] <- 0.2
      mc[c(n+2,w),n:n+1] <- 0.2
    }
  }

  for (m in seq(3,9,2)){               # every group of 12 are given correlation of 0.3
     for (w in seq(12,60,12)){          # these variables are the rest.
       mc[m:m+1,c(1:m-1,m+2:w)] <- 0.2
       mc[c(1:m-1,m+2:w),m:m+1] <- 0.2
     }
  }
  ```

The first loop works well, but not the second and third ones. I get this error message:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, m:m + 1, c(1:m - 1, m + 2:w), value = 0.2) : 
  subscript out of bounds

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, m:m + 1, c(1:m - 1, m + 2:w), value = 0.2) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I would really appreciate any hints, since I don't see the loop commands get to exceed the matrix dimensions. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: try putting `cat()` or `print()` statements in your code to see what's going on, or use `options(error=recover)` to have R dump you into a browser when an error occurs ...

Comment: Note that `:` takes precedence over `+`. E.g., `n:n+1` is the same as `n+1`. I guess you want `n:(n+1)`.

Comment: @Roland  "Extra parentheses FTW"  :-)

Comment: For googlers: several subscript out of bounds questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318568/r-error-subscript-out-of-bounds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831786/error-in-tmpj-subscript-out-of-bounds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333525/error-in-tmpk-subscript-out-of-bounds-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `:` takes precedence over `+`. E.g., `n:n+1` is the same as `n+1`. I guess you want `n:(n+1)`.

The maximal value of `w` is 60:

```
w <- 60
m <- 1
m+2:w
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
#[49] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61
```

And 61 is out of bounds. You need to add a lot of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks Roland for your time =)